# B-2 visa application

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, applications

I am applying for a B-2 visa and have the following questions:

1) I lost my expired passport on which I visited Dubai in 2011. Should I mention it in DS-160?

2) I am a government officer. I mention my salary and there is no option for other sources of income. Will I have to present those additional documents at the interview?

3)I am 28 years old and unmarried, going to visit New York and to see my younger brother who studies there. What are the chances of my visa application being approved?

Comment: What are you expecting for question 3 out of interest? A percentage? We can't know what they're thinking, we can only suggest really for parts 1 and 2...

Comment: mark mayo so plz suggest me about 1 and 2 question plz

Comment: you didn't answer my question.  By we I meant the site, not necessarily me - I don't know enough about US visas.

Comment: @MarkMayo there definitely factors that increase/decrease likelihood of rejection. Some of them are well known, if you are young single woman currently unemployed your chances of getting visa are close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you lost a passport then answer yes. I do not quite see how this can be a question. Are you asking whether you should lie on the DS-160???? Of course not! The two fundamental rules of dealing with immigration officers: 1) never lie 2) never offer information unasked. BTW at the interview they will want to see the previous passports.

I do not get this question. What additional documents? You have documents showing other sources of income, like a rental? In that case, you are running a (one person) business and so

> If you are a business owner, enter an average amount of net income you receive from the business after expenses.

So I would enter the total amount you are getting a month from every source that you can back up with paperwork.